# Give Scroll view to only edittext in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

need to give scrollview to only edittext field not give scroll to whole layout
in this layout i am using edittext and i need to give scrollview only that edittext not all layout
here is my code
[See here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVxfB.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarforprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/electricle" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/leftarrow"

                android:textColor="@color/demo"
                android:textSize="0sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-65.5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/demo"

                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="16dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtservicedetails"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical">


                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/editText_requirement"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                                    android:background="#fff"
                                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "
                                    android:gravity="top"

                                    android:hint="Your Requirement (optional)"
                                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                                    android:padding="6dp"
                                    android:textColor="#000" />

                                <DatePicker
                                    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/et_dateof_visit"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                                    android:background="#fff"
                                    android:focusable="false"
                                    android:hint="Date Of Visit"
                                    android:inputType="date"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:padding="5dp"
                                    android:textColor="#000" />

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/et_time"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                    android:background="#fff"
                                    android:focusable="false"
                                    android:hint="Time Of Visit"
                                    android:inputType="time"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:padding="5dp"
                                    android:textColor="#000" />

                                <EditText

                                    android:id="@+id/et_noofperson"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                    android:background="#fff"
                                    android:focusable="true"
                                    android:hint="No Of Person You Need"
                                    android:inputType="number"
                                    android:maxLength="2"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:padding="5dp"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:text="" />

                                <EditText

                                    android:id="@+id/et_serviceaddress"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                    android:background="#fff"
                                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890/-,: "
                                    android:focusable="true"
                                    android:gravity="top"
                                    android:hint="Service Address"
                                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                                    android:maxLines="4"
                                    android:padding="10dp"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:text="" />


                            </LinearLayout>
                        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
                            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_green"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Submit"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/btnsubmit"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are not at all clear about what you want

Comment: i want to give scrollview to edittext field only not submit button and first textview

Comment: This question will keep on receiving down votes till you edit the question and add diagrams or images explaining what your problem is

Comment: also added a image

Answer (score 0):

Try something below like this,

```
 View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent motionEvent) 
{
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
 {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

I hope this may help you,All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure if I have understood your question right. I assume that you want to make the `EditText`(s) scroll, while keeping the top `TextView` and bottom `Button` fixed in place.

Try this. I'll begin by making a `LinearLayout` as the primary container and add the `TextView`, `ScrollView`, and `Button` as child layouts.

Then all the `EditText`(s) that need to be scrolled can be added to a `LinearLayout` added as a child to the `ScrollView`.

Check out this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarforprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:titleTextColor="#ffffff"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--Put all your scrollable content in here-->

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have give `layout_weight` property to the `ScrollView` to ensure the `Button` always stays at the bottom.

PS: Leave a comment if this was not your required solution.

Answer (score 0):

android:scrollHorizontally="true"  use this